# Sending code from Python buffer to IPython session running from M-x ansi-term

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

Say I open a terminal emulator in Emacs with `M-x ansi-term`. This opens a buffer in Emacs with the shell of my choice. Say I then run `ipython` from this shell. Can I send code to this `ipython` session from another buffer with Python code in Emacs? If so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a minor mode for this purpose (except it is not IPython-specific and I mostly use it for shell scripts): [isend-mode](https://github.com/ffevotte/isend-mode.el).

Here is how you would use it:

1. Open an `ansi-term` buffer:

   <kbd>M-x</kbd>`ansi-term`<kbd>RET</kbd>`/usr/bin/ipython`<kbd>RET</kbd>
2. Open the buffer with the code you want to execute, and associate it to the interpreter buffer:

   <kbd>M-x</kbd>`isend-associate`<kbd>RET</kbd>`*ansi-term*`<kbd>RET</kbd>
3. Hit <kbd>C-RET</kbd> in the python buffer to send the current line to the interpreter in the `ansi-term` buffer.

Comment: This is awesome Francesco. Does it only support sending the current line? (i.e. as opposed to sending a region, or a full buffer).

Comment: If the region is active, it will send it instead of sending the current line (actually, it will send all lines spanned by the region, *i.e* no line will be only partially sent). To send the whole buffer, I use `C-x h C-RET` (but I very seldom use this since my main usage is to interpret scripts line by line or part by part)

Comment: Thanks @Francesco, the only thing I noticed is that `isend` does not cope well with code snippets that have code blocks with indentation in them. E.g. if I select code that has an `if` block or a `for` loop with some other unindented code, `isend` will not send the indentation the way IPython expects it. Wouldn't it be better to send the code selected to the shell by calling `%paste` in IPython? (i.e. you would have `isend` copy the code to the Emacs clipboard and then have it call `%paste` in the IPython buffer). This will allow `isend` to cope with arbitrarily complex code snipetts.

Comment: I think your problem was related to the fact that interactive IPython interpreters expect empty lines at the end of loops or other indented constructs. By default, `isend` ignores such lines, but I've uploaded a new version which can be told to send empty lines using `(setq isend-skip-empty-lines nil)`.

Comment: Thanks Francesco. I tried the new version but problems persist. The reason is that indentation has meaning in Python (and IPython), so if I select code that comes, say, from inside a loop, IPython complains with  `unexpected indent` because the code is indented. The only way to solve the problem with `isend`  would be if you remove any extra indentation from the code block (but keeping the relative indentation between lines) before sending it to the buffer. I think this would be an elegant solution, and it should work with other shells as well (other shells are not picky about indentation).

Comment: Well, this is a different problem altogether. This would require `isend-mode` to first modify the region before sending it, when the purpose of `isend-mode` is only to send (unmodified) parts of a buffer to an interpreter. Anyways, SO might not be the best place to discuss such things. Please open an issue at [github](https://github.com/ffevotte/isend-mode.el) if you want to discuss this topic further.

Comment: Francesco, here is an easy solution to this problem that would work great with IPython: Once the code is in the Emacs kill ring, we could have a command that calls `%paste` in the IPython buffer. `%paste` will take care of adjusting indentation for you automatically. To do this, it would be great to have a command in `isend-mode` that can be associated with a string variable in elisp. Whenever the command is invoked, this command will send to the terminal whatever is in that variable (the user could choose to fix the variable to `%paste` when working with IPython).

Comment: @user273158 I think I found a way to keep most of `isend-mode` non-iPython-specific and still be able to handle iPython's `%paste` command. I uploaded a new version on github, in the `ipython` branch. You'll probably want to install the `isend-default-ipython-setup` hook as explained in the documentation.
On another note and as I said earlier, I don't think StackOverflow to be a good place to discuss this; please post feature requests or report bugs on github (It'll take you seconds to create an account there if you don't already have one).

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun send-buffer-to-ipython ()
  "Send current buffer to the running ipython process."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((ipython-buffer "*ansi-term*") ; the buffer name of your running terminal
         (proc (get-buffer-process ipython-buffer)))
    (unless proc
      (error "no process found"))
    (save-buffer)
    (process-send-string proc
                         (format "execfile(\"%s\")\n" (buffer-file-name)))
    (pop-to-buffer ipython-buffer)      ; show ipython and select it
    ;; (display-buffer ipython-buffer)  ; show ipython but don't select it
    ))
```

Then bind command `send-buffer-to-ipython` to any key you like. I bind it to `C-c C-c`

```
(define-key python-mode-map [?\C-c ?\C-c] 'send-buffer-to-ipython)
```

Comment: When text is large, I think sending a command to load and execute current file is better. This is also the way how python.el implements it, except that in python.el `python-send-region` saves current buffer's content to a temp file and send the command to load the temp file.

Answer (score 2):

with python-mode.el

M-x customize-variable RET py-shell-name RET ansi-term

M-x ansi-term RET ipython RET

C-c C-c from Python-buffer than executes in IPython shell

Caveat: a shebang precedes default py-shell-name

https://launchpad.net/python-mode/trunk/6.0.12/+download/python-mode.el-6.0.12.tar.gz

Comment: Thanks Andreas. What do you mean with `Caveat: a shebang precedes default py-shell-name`. Do you mean that if I have a shebang in the script from which I want to send my code, the shebang would take precedence over the value of my `py-shell-name`?

Comment: yes. AFAIS executing through ansi-term only works if no shebang is set - which is a bug.

Comment: Andreas, how would I set this up if I have multiple `ansi_term` buffers? Can I just rename the Emacs buffer running IPython to something else and pass this as an argument to `py-shell-name`? Or how should we cope with multiple ansi-terms?