# Emacs Python Mode and Executing commands

Tags: emacs, python-2.7, emacs24, python-mode

I have emacs24 installed on windows in `C:\Program Files(x64)` and python2.7 under `C:\Python27`

I've tried to install python mode to send commands to the interpreter from emacs. My init.el file in `Users/myname/.emacs.d`:

```
(setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.1.1")
(add-to-list 'load-path py-install-directory)
(require 'python-mode)
(setq py-shell-name "C:\Python27\python.exe")

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(py-shell-name "C:\\Python27\\python.exe"))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

I've put the python mode files in: `C:\Users\myname\.emacs.d\python-mode.el-6.1.1`

An interactive python session can be formed in a buffer by choosing the PyShell > Default Intepreter option in the menu, but if I open a .py file and try to run a hellow world like by going to the menu PyExec > Execute Statement I get errors of this nature:

`Opening output file: no such file or directory, c:/Users/Ben/AppData/Local/Temp/C-/Python27/python.exe-705218Y.py`

How can I set up so I can edit python code and then send lines to the python interpreter in another buffer without this error?

Comment: An other approach is developed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13445153/1225607)

Answer (score 3):

You are using `setq` and `custom-set-variables` to set `py-shell-name`.  If I remember correctly, `custom-set-variables` does not work if you use `setq` before it.  Also, you need to escape backslash when you write it in string literals.  Using one of the following should solve your problem.

To use `setq`, fix backslashes:

```
(setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.1.1")
(add-to-list 'load-path py-install-directory)
(require 'python-mode)
(setq py-shell-name "C:\\Python27\\python.exe")
```

To use `custom-set-variables`, just remove `setq`:

```
(setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.1.1")
(add-to-list 'load-path py-install-directory)
(require 'python-mode)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(py-shell-name "C:\\Python27\\python.exe"))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```